# Generate a form permalink

Tags: javascript, html

How can I create a permalink for my form [here](http://ambo100.com/salmoneus/database/itemdb.html) so that all the values of the form can be saved in the URL?

Comment: Define "permalink" for your needs here.  Usually for something like this it means that the link would include an ID which would pre-populate the form based on stored values associated with that ID (the ID of a record which was previously created via that form).  But what you describe sounds more like you want to supply new values in the link and have the form automatically fill in those values.  Can you clarify?

Comment: That's correct. I'd like all the values of the input fields to be saved in the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the pure JavaScript solution, then using *#hash* might be an easiest way to go:

```
http://ambo100.com/salmoneus/database/itemdb.html#{"name":"John","price":10}
```

In this case you are free in choosing the syntax (and not limited by the query string). This could be processed by the following simple JS code:

```
try {
    var data = JSON.parse(location.hash.substr(1, location.hash.length));
    $.each(data, function(key, value) { // assuming you're using jQuery
        $(':input[name=' + key + ']').val(value);
    });
}
except {

}
```

Comment: How will I be able to generate a URL based on the forms IDs and would it be necessary to encode and decode the URL?

Comment: _#hash_ part isn't sent to server, hence you don't have to encode it. For generating the JSON use `JSON.stringify({name: 'John', price: 10})`. Assuming that you've created the object by iterating over form elements

Comment: I think I'll need some help implementing it :s

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for isn't really a "permalink" so much as it's just a way to provide someone with a link which automatically fills in form values.  A "permalink" links to an existing record, whereas you're asking to create a new record (based on your comment).

If you want all the values in the URL, then what you can do is have a URL like this:

> ~/itemdb.html?field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3...

And so on.  (Replace the fields with actual meaningful field names, of course.)

The page has an `.html` extension.  Is there any server-side logic here, or is it just a static page?  If there's any server-side processing, then you can capture those values (GET values, since a link creates just a GET request) in your server-side code and pre-populate the fields.

If you don't have any server-side logic driving this, you can still do it with JavaScript.  There are a number of methods to [get URL parameters in JavaScript](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20get%20url%20parameter).  What you decide to do is up to you.  Once you have the values, you can just set the values of the corresponding form elements accordingly.  For example (assuming jQuery):

```
var fieldValue = GetFieldValueSomehow('fieldName');
$('#elementName').val(fieldValue);
```

You'll want to do some basic input checking, of course.

Comment: I have a basic understanding of PHP I could change the filetype if that would make things easier.

Comment: @Ambo100: If you can do it in PHP on the server-side, that would probably be the better option.

Comment: I'd like to use the GET function without loading a new page. I'm also aware of a limit in the length of the URL that could possibly cut out some information (depending on how long the limit is) which could be a problem.

Comment: Ambo - if you do it using Javascript you could actually put the information into the Hash of the location. This means that users can still be served a cached page.

Comment: @Ambo100: There's no need to load a new page in either scenario.  It's just a question of where you're more comfortable doing your coding.  (As well as any possible security concerns your application may have, given that JavaScript code is delivered to the client whereas PHP code runs on the server out of the client's reach.)

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to save the values to some form of database.

You would then need to have a page which pulls the data out of the database querying against something passed in the URL. This could be anything but the simple solution would be to use an auto incrementing primary key column in the database.

To pass the unique value which matches to this column either add the code in a querystring or better still use routing.

There are many more options on how to create the link. Consider the codes produced by URL shorteners. Also with routing some websites produce a friendly link with a name based on what is entered in the form and then pin the database ID at the end which is the actual bit which points to the right data.

Another solution would be to actually create a flat HTML page on the server with the data in the form and give the user back the link to that page created.

Comment: I wouldn't want to create a database to solve this. I think the last suggestion seems the most reasonable although I'm not sure how I can do that.

Comment: What language are you using? Back-end wise?

Comment: Like PHP. AS other people are suggesting you can put the data into the URL but two things to watch out for are:
a) the length issue
b) to clean any unpleasant characters